# Flutter Stripe and Firebase Initialisation

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-stripe

I'm trying to implement Stripe to my web app using Firebase. I've tried a lot of different ways, but so far nothing works.
I'm trying with flutter_stripe, but when I want to do that:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  Stripe.publishableKey = 'my publishable key';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "my-project-APIKey",
      authDomain: "my-project.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "my-project-id",
      storageBucket: "my-project.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "************",
      appId: "*:************:web:**********************"
    )
  );
  auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
    if(user == null) {
      auth.signInAnonymously();
      visitsCounter();
      initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => runApp(const Main()));
    } else {
      visitsCounter();
      initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => runApp(const Main()));
    }
  });
}
```

Firebase doesn't work anymore and I absolutely need it. I tried to put the publishable key before or after the Firebase.initializeApp(), nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?